# Set Table cellspacing color

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table overlays on top an image *as its background image*.

I want to set the **cellspacing color to white** so that the columns looks separated.

However I could not o set the `<table>` background color because it affects the `<td>` background color too in which I want it to stay transparent.

Each of the `<td>` has its own border color as well, hence I could not tweak with its border color to white.

```
<div id="container">
  <img id="mybackgroundimage" />
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td class="green"></td>
      <td class="green"></td>
      <td class="red"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="red"></td>
      <td class="green"></td>
      <td class="red"></td>
    </tr>
 </table>
</div>




        #container{
            position: relative;
        }

        #table {
            border-spacing: 2px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
        }

           #table td.green {
               border-color: green;
           }

           #table td.red {
               border-color: red;
           }
```

Anyone could advise?

Comment: HTML code if possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option 1: use solid outline for cells.

```css
#table {
  border-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#table td {
  outline: 2px solid #ccc;
}

#table td.green {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#table td.red {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="green">Cell one</td>
    <td>Cell two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell three</td>
    <td class="red">Cell four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Option 2: use box shadow with zero blur radius.

```css
#table {
  border-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#table td {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 2px #ccc;
}

#table td.green {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

#table td.red {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td class="green">Cell one</td>
    <td>Cell two</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Cell three</td>
    <td class="red">Cell four</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, you just want to put a background image to your table, and to collapse border?

Here I set `background-color` to red, but you can use an image as well.

```css
table, th, td {
  border:2px solid white;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <div style="background-color:red;padding:10px;">
    <table>
      <tr><td>A</td><td>A</td><td>A</td></tr>
      <tr><td>A</td><td>A</td><td>A</td></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</html>
```

Example with a background-image: https://jsfiddle.net/c8evw5eo/

Answer (score 1):

```css
.row1{
border: 15px solid white
}
.row2{
border: 15px solid white
}
```

```html
<html> 
  <body >
    <table border=1 bgcolor=green cellspacing=15>
      <tr> <td class="row1"> January </td> <td class="row1"> February </td> </tr> 
      <tr> <td  class="row2"> March </td> <td  class="row2"> April </td> 
      </tr> 
    </table> 
  </body> 
</html>
```